# Twincat 3 Simultaneous FTP Connections

Tags: ftp, plc, ftp-client, twincat, twincat-ads

I am attempting to run multiple FTP connections to upload multiple files at once to a FTP server.
I am using FB_FTP_OpenEx(Active Mode), FB_FTP_FileUpload, and FB_FTP_Close.
However, when opening multiple connections,the FTP client returns error code "32769 - Internal Error TwinCAT FTP Client".

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

Thank you.

I have checked for limitations on simultaneous connections imposed by the FTP server.

The FTP function works when only 1 connections is established but fails with multiple connections.

Comment: Do you have the FTP function blocks instantiated separately for each connection?